# Comparação de datas em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data

Olá preciso comparar a data atual com a digitada pelo usuário porém os segundos impedem essa verificação:

```js
var data_publicacao = new Date($('#frm-data').val());
    console.log(data_publicacao);
    var data_atual = new Date();
    console.log(data_atual);
    if (data_publicacao != undefined) {
        if (data_publicacao > data_atual || data_publicacao < data_atual) {
            alert("Sua notícia foi salva, mas ainda não foi publicada! Aguarde.");
        }
        else {
            noticias.push(noticia);
            atualizarLista(noticia);
            alert("Notícia publicada!");
        }
    }
```

Existe algum modo de tirar os segundos de maneira fácil sem que deixe o código poluído?

Comment: Sempre que preciso trabalhar com datas, quando possível uso a biblioteca [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) que tem métodos pra facilitar isso

Comment: A datas a se comparar seria o que? Dias, meses, anos?

Comment: O que eu costumo fazer é pegar o .getDate(), .getMonth(), e .getFullYear(), e insiro dentro da data, assim ele gera apenas o dia mês e ano, enquanto o horário fica sempre 00:00:00. De qualquer forma, não sei se isso pra você é considerado poluir o código.

Comment: Ricardo -> Vou dar uma pesquisada

Comment: LeAndrade -> Seria a data e a hora

Comment: Máttheus -> Entendo, pse assim não dá, tbm preciso da hora

Comment: bom, se não te encomodar escrever, apenas adicione o getHours() e getMinutes(). Só vai dar mais trabalho, mas funciona.

Comment: Mas como faço para colocar todos esses metodos em uma variavel?
ele não aceita dataAtual.getDate().getMonth()...

Comment: como disse, se você não se importa em poluir seu código, pode fazer `var a = new Date(); ` e então `var dataAtual = new Date(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate(), a.getHours(), a.getMinutes());`

Comment: Cara no seu caso aí é como o Matheus disse, vai ter que ficar grande o código, o javascript é meio chato para trabalhar com data. Ou vc pega tudo com o **new Date()** ou separa por métodos **getHours(), getMinutes()**. Vc escolhe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer comparar a data e hora, mas ignorando os segundos, uma alternativa é usar o método `setSeconds` e mudar o valor dos segundos para zero.
Recomendo mudar também os milissegundos, assim você garante que só as horas e minutos serão considerados:

```js
// uma data qualquer
var d = new Date();
// mudar segundos e milissegundos para zero
d.setSeconds(0);
d.setMilliseconds(0);
console.log(d);
```

**Faça isso com as duas datas que você quer comparar** (`data_publicacao` e `data_atual`), assim você garante que os segundos (e as frações de segundo) não irão interferir na comparação.

Para compará-las, não adianta usar `>` e `<` (nem quaisquer outros operadores)  diretamente, pois nem sempre funciona (se não me engano, em alguns browsers pode funcionar, mas não é garantido que funcione em todos). O melhor é [usar o valor retornado por `getTime()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493018), que retorna o valor numérico do Unix timestamp (o número de milissegundos desde 1970-01-01T00:00Z).

Então seu `if` ficaria assim:

```
if (data_publicacao.getTime() > data_atual.getTime() 
   || data_publicacao.getTime() < data_atual.getTime()) {
```

Só um detalhe, este `if` significa: se a data de publicação for maior que a data atual (ou seja, no futuro) **ou** se a data de publicação for menor que a data atual (ou seja, no passado).

Se a data de publicação estiver no passado ou no futuro, você quer que entre no `if`, é isso mesmo? Ou seja, qualquer data que não seja a atual vai entrar neste `if`.

Enfim, esta é uma maneira de desconsiderar os segundos na comparação. Eu só revisaria o critério do `if`, pois para mim está meio estranho...

Answer (score 1):

**toLocaleDateString()** - string apenas de data no formato localizado no seu sistema.

```js
var data_atual = new Date();

console.log(data_atual.toLocaleDateString());
```

> O que você quer é dado na resposta do @hkotsubo
>
> vou mastigar para você!

```
var data_publicacao = new Date($('#frm-data').val());
data_publicacao.setSeconds(0);
data_publicacao.setMilliseconds(0);
data_publicacao = (data_publicacao.getTime());

var data_atual = new Date();
// mudar segundos e milissegundos para zero
data_atual.setSeconds(0);
data_atual.setMilliseconds(0);
data_atual = (data_atual.getTime());
    
if (data_publicacao > data_atual || data_publicacao < data_atual) {
.....
```

Comment: mas ae ele n pega a hora, preciso da data e da hora para cumprir as exigências da atividade :/

Comment: Bom saber disso.
Agora vem a pergunta. Se ele transforma a data em string, como ele pode comparar se uma data é maior ou menor que a outra se são strings e não datas?

Comment: Pse fiquei com essa duvida na aula, o professor diz que mesmo passando pra string ele faz a comparação(???), agora como é feita ele não me disse...

Answer (score -1):

Consegui [encontrar a resposta no GitHub](https://github.com/Lautert/helpers/blob/master/javascript.helpers.js), segue as instruções:

```
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Lautert/helpers/master/javascript.helpers.js"></script>

var d = new Date();
console.log(d.toDate('dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii:ss'));

console.log(d.toDate('mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii:ss'));

console.log(d.toDate('yyyy-mm-dd'));

console.log(d.toDate('yyyy-dd'));
```